# ionic build failed due to Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRAnalytics'

Tags: ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, ionic4, firebase-analytics

Using ionic 4 cordova build tool , while taking build im getting build error in fire analytics plugin.

I tried remove the plugin in package json but it installing by default when i try to build or adding the platform.

````
"cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "~6.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": "^6.1.2",
"cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": {
       "ANDROID_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_VERSION": "22.0.+",
       "ANDROIDX_CORE_VERSION": "1.6.+",
       "IOS_FIREBASE_POD_VERSION": "~> 8.8.0"
     } ```


[![enter image description here][1]][1]


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMTcx.jpg
````

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this? I understand that you forced a version 8.8.0 which is different from the default 6.something.

Answer (score -1):

The error is because when we use cocopods, we need to get a build from
YourProject.xcworkspace (not YourProject.xcodeproj)
still if you face an error in firebase analytics...

None of your spec sources contains a spec satisfying the dependencies: `Firebase/Analytics (> 6.1.0), Firebase/Analytics (= 6.1.0, > 6.1.0)`.
Make sure your local Cocoapods repo is up-to-date by running pod repo update then run pod install in /your_project/platforms/ios/.

Cocoapods
This plugin relies on cordova@9/cordova-ios@5 support for the CocoaPods dependency manager in order to satisfy the iOS Firebase SDK library dependencies.

Please make sure you have cocoapods@>=1.11.2 installed in your iOS build environment - setup instructions can be found here.

If building your project in Xcode, you need to open YourProject.xcworkspace (not YourProject.xcodeproj) so both your Cordova app project and the Pods project will be loaded into Xcode.

You can list the pod dependencies in your Cordova iOS project by installing cocoapods-dependencies:

sudo gem install cocoapods-dependencies
cd platforms/ios/
pod dependencies